# Do you have any examples of 2 assets that are non linearly correlated? And any models that calculate portfolio risk based on non-linear correlation?

Tags: portfolio-management, finance, correlation

Do you have any examples of 2 assets that are non linearly correlated?  And any models that calculate portfolio risk based on non-linear correlation?

Comment: Immediate easy example : asset x, and an option on asset x. Though, you should note that this is not correlation, but dependance. But really dependance is what will drive a lot of these, and what causes correlation skew.